# Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error code and have no idea why any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`@USER`.`meter`, CONSTRAINT `meter_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`location_code`) REFERENCES `location` (`code`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

```
CREATE TABLE meter (
    `code` CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    `type` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    location_code CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pri_meter 
PRIMARY KEY (`code`),
    CONSTRAINT meter_FK
FOREIGN KEY (location_code) 
    REFERENCES location (`code`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE );

INSERT INTO meter VALUES ('G1','Gas','Testing Unit','NULL');
INSERT INTO meter VALUES ('G2','Gas','NULL','U1');
INSERT INTO meter VALUES ('E1','Electric','NULL','U1');
INSERT INTO meter VALUES ('G3','Gas','NULL','U2');
INSERT INTO meter VALUES ('G4','Gas','NULL','U2');
INSERT INTO meter VALUES ('E2','Electric','NULL','U2');
INSERT INTO meter VALUES ('E3','Electric','NULL','C1');
```

Comment: `'NULL'` is not a valid `location_code`.

Comment: You have `location_code` `not null`, but in your first record you have a `NULL` for `location_code`.

Comment: Before understanding why this happens, you need to know what a foreign key is. Do you know what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreign key (FK) in this instance is "location_code".  The first row of data you're trying to insert has a null "location_code".

FKs require you to have a matching primary key in the related table. (location)

It's very unlikely "location" "code" has null as a value - and without a matching value for your FK, you cannot insert data into your "meter" table.

Easiest solution - replace the null in your first insert:

```
INSERT INTO meter VALUES ('G1','Gas','Testing Unit','U1');
```